PDDL check for conditionals
I am struggling to understand how PDDL works. With this question I am interested in knowing if the problem is about syntax, edge-cases or just me understanding PDDL wrong. Especially the following: When I check for a conditional with the when clause, does it alter the predicate? In the following example, when I check for (light-on ?room) does it switch the light-on predicate to a True value? If so how to then encode such effect?
This is the domain of the problem:
(define (domain vampire)
    (:requirements :conditional-effects)
    (:predicates
        (light-on ?r)
        (slayer-is-alive)
        (slayer-is-in ?r)
        (vampire-is-alive)
        (vampire-is-in ?r)
        (fighting)
        ;
        ; static predicates
        (NEXT-ROOM ?r ?rn)
        (CONTAINS-GARLIC ?r)
    )

    (:action toggle-light
        :parameters (?anti-clockwise-neighbor ?room ?clockwise-neighbor)
        :precondition (and
            (NEXT-ROOM ?anti-clockwise-neighbor ?room)
            (NEXT-ROOM ?room ?clockwise-neighbor)
            (not (fighting))
        )
        :effect (and
            (when
                (and (not(light-on ?room)) (vampire-is-in ?room) (not(light-on ?clockwise-neighbor)))
                (and (light-on ?room) (not(vampire-is-in ?room)) (vampire-is-in ?clockwise-neighbor))
            )
            (when
                (and (not(light-on ?room)) (vampire-is-in ?room) (not(light-on ?anti-clockwise-neighbor)))
                (and (light-on ?room) (not(vampire-is-in ?room)) (vampire-is-in ?anti-clockwise-neighbor))
            )
            (when
                (and (not(light-on ?room)) (vampire-is-in ?room) (not(light-on ?anti-clockwise-neighbor)) (not(light-on ?clockwise-neighbor)) )
                (and (light-on ?room) (not(vampire-is-in ?room)) (vampire-is-in ?anti-clockwise-neighbor))
            )
            (when
                (and (not(light-on ?room)) (vampire-is-in ?room) (light-on ?anti-clockwise-neighbor) (light-on ?clockwise-neighbor))
                (and (light-on ?room) (not(vampire-is-in ?room)) (vampire-is-in ?clockwise-neighbor))
            )
            ;;
            ;;
            (when
                (and (light-on ?room) (slayer-is-in ?room) (light-on ?clockwise-neighbor))
                (and (not (light-on ?room)) (not(slayer-is-in ?room)) (slayer-is-in ?clockwise-neighbor))
            )
            (when
                (and (light-on ?room) (slayer-is-in ?room) (not(light-on ?clockwise-neighbor)))
                (and (not (light-on ?room)) (not(slayer-is-in ?room)) (slayer-is-in ?anti-clockwise-neighbor))
            )
        )
    )

    (:action watch-fight
        :parameters (?room)
        :precondition (and
            (slayer-is-in ?room)
            (slayer-is-alive)
            (vampire-is-in ?room)
            (vampire-is-alive)
            (fighting)
        )
        :effect (and
             (when
                (CONTAINS-GARLIC ?room)
                (not(vampire-is-alive))
             )
             (when
                (light-on ?room)
                (not(vampire-is-alive))
             )
             (when
                 (not(light-on ?room))
                 (not(slayer-is-alive))
             )
        )
    )
)

and this is a possible problem:
(define (problem p01)
(:domain vampire)
;
; Room1 Room2 Room3 Room4 Room5
; 1S    0     1     0G    0V
;
(:objects
   room1
   room2
   room3
   room4
   room5
)
(:init
   (light-on room1)
   (light-on room3)

   (slayer-is-alive)
   (slayer-is-in room1)

   (vampire-is-alive)
   (vampire-is-in room5)

   (CONTAINS-GARLIC room4)

   (NEXT-ROOM room1 room2)
   (NEXT-ROOM room2 room3)
   (NEXT-ROOM room3 room4)
   (NEXT-ROOM room4 room5)
   (NEXT-ROOM room5 room1)
)
(:goal (and
   (slayer-is-alive)
   (not (vampire-is-alive))
   (slayer-is-in room3)
))
)


Conditional effects are all of the following form…
(when <cond> <eff>)

…where <cond> can be a fluent or conjunction of fluents or something like that, and <eff> is similarly a fluent or a conjunction of ones. When you execute an action in state s and it takes you to state s’, the way to interpret a conditional effect is: “when <cond> holds in state s, then <eff> should hold in state s’”.
There are some extra details (disjunctions and existentials are ok in a condition but not an effect, if you have multiple conditional effects fire, then add effects take precedence, etc), but that’s the general process. Important thing to keep in mind is that <cond> only refers to what might hold in state s, while <eff> is describing what’s going to change.
